# How can I set class properties when the values are specified as an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, properties, iteration

For my object constructor, my first argument is an array of values that corresponds to the length of my class' properties. I want to iterate over that input array and initialize each property with the respective value in the array.

```
function obj = Waveform(required, options, varargin)
            objProperties = reshape(properties(obj), [1, size(properties(obj))]);

            for index = 1:size(required, 2)
                set(obj, objProperties(:, index), required(:, index));
            end
end
```

I know that loop works but I do not know how or if it is possible to initialize in the above manner.

In its current state, the program returns the following error: Cannot find 'set' method for Waveform class.

Comment: Have you tried running this? Does it work, or does it give an error?

Comment: This does return an error: it says that matlab cannot find the 'set method for WaveForm class'.

Comment: Your class will only have `set/get` methods by default if you derive/inherit from [a class that implements them](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html). Otherwise, you have to implement them yourself.

Comment: It is my understanding that overloading set/get is only necessary when there is custom functionality involved — I am merely trying to initialize each property automatically in a matter that is functionally analogous to ```obj.Property1 = Value1;```

Comment: This seems like a wildly flakey way to set properties. You have no idea what order the properties will be in, especially if you want to use the class without having to read the source code, or if the class is modified? Why are name-value pairs (a well established method for inputting optional parameters in MATLAB) not preferable?

Comment: @Wolfie Without context, I agree wholeheartedly. In this instance, however, this constructor will be fed values from various static factory methods, thus one can be sure that the provided arguments are in the correct order and themselves correct.

Comment: @ts1624 I'll happily assume this is not as robust as you think it is, but I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class doesn't have a `set` method implemented, you can't use `set(obj, ...)` to achieve this. You will only have `set/get` methods by default if your class derives/inherits from [a built-in class that implements them](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html).

If you don't want to inherit from one of these classes or implement `set/get` methods yourself, you can use [dynamic field referencing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) to achieve this. Here's an example class:

```
classdef Waveform

  properties
    a
    b
    c
  end

  methods
    function obj = Waveform(required)
      objProperties = properties(obj);
      for index = 1:numel(required)
        obj.(objProperties{index}) = required(index);
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And you can create new objects as follows:

```
>> obj = Waveform([1 2 3])

obj = 

  Waveform with properties:

    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3

>> obj = Waveform([1 2])  % Only pass 2 values...

obj = 

  Waveform with properties:

    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: []  % ...and the third property is not initialized
```

**However**, this seems like a very fragile approach that would be difficult to maintain and could easily break if you ever modify your class by adding or removing properties. I would suggest passing property values to your [constructor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#bvf4llf-1) as separate arguments, or possibly making use of [input validation methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html).